# I grow as others die

Tags: riddle

Although I am dead,
I grow as others die.
Acids hate me.
My home is often a tray.
Sometimes I fall before I can get home.

The answer must meet all conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for

> cigarette ash

Although I am dead,

> Ash is the remains of the burnt portion of a cigarette.

I grow as others die.

> As a cigarette burns, there becomes more and more ash.

Acids hate me.

> I had to look this up.   All ash is alkaline, so ash can neutralize acid.

My home is often a tray.

> An ashtray.

Sometimes I fall before I can get home.

> The ash can fall off a cigarette.

Comment: +1 Good job.  Your answer does not need to be two words, however.

Answer (score 5):

You are an

> inebriated vampire

Although I am dead,

> "undead" would be the more technically correct term here, but vampires are often colloquially referred to as being dead.  And let's face it, "Although I am undead" would have totally given away the whole riddle.

I grow as others die,

> The vampire gains strength, as it feeds upon fresh victims.

Acids hate me,

> Holy Water burns vampires like acid, which understandably leaves your *actual* working-class acids out of a job.

My home is often a tray

> In between death and rising, a vampire will typically "live" on a tray in a morgue.

Sometimes I fall before I can get home.

> Hey buddy, are you all right?  Do you need me to call you a cab?

Comment: I'm certain that this isn't the answer you were intending.  But it was fun to write.  :)

Comment: lmao, this is hilarious.  It does meat all the conditions except the last one.  Very entertaining to read +1

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

> Bread

**Reasoning:**

Although I am dead,

> Bread is dead

I grow as others die.

> Bread/yeast molds and continues to grow

Acids hate me.

> Bread is a great food to eat to combat acid reflux

My home is often a tray.

> From the bakery it goes onto a bread tray and loaded into a truck, of which it sits in this bread tray until it sits on the store shelf, and then it goes to its new home from there: a kitchen pantry

Sometimes I fall before I can get home.

> Bread, like a cake, can fall in the oven while being baked. Other notable instances would be falling from the loaf from the counter (my most common reason), or falling from your plate.

Comment: This is a great answer, +1 .  It was not the answer I had in mind, and "The acids hate me" criteria is a bit weak on this one.  and here: http://www.rense.com/1.mpicons/acidalka.htm  - your answer is listed as acidic.

Comment: Thanks, I tried! Bread seems to work for my own acid reflux battles, so I forgot it's actually acidic.

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

> Cookies

**How I came to this conclusion:**

Although I am dead

> Cookies are non-living things

I grow as others die

> Cookies are being baked while other cookies get eaten "die"

Acids hate me

> Stomach acids "hate" cookies that is why the burn

My home is often a tray

> Tray of cookies

Sometimes I fall before I can get home

> Fall of or get eaten and normally cookies don't get back to the tray unless they serve it on trays